# Image Hover-HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background, hover

I am having trouble creating a different image to appear when you place your curser over the original image.  Heres my code without the rest of my listed buttons:

```
<nav class="buttons">
<ul>
    <li class="left">
    <a class="home" href="www.google.com">
    <img src="img/Home_2.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Css:

```
.buttons img{width: 190px; margin:0px; padding:0px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:55px;}
.buttons ul{list-style-type: none; margin:0px; padding:0px}

.left{float:left}
.home:hover {background: url(../img/Home_crack.PNG)}
```

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: Okay great suggestions, however when I hover over the "home button" now the stuff in the float tweeks out.  Heres the code with the full float properties:

HTML:

```
<nav class="buttons">
<ul>
    <li class="left">
    <a class="home" href="www.google.com">
    <img src="img/Home_2.png"></a></li>

    <li class="left">
    <a href="www.google.com" class="menu">
    <img src="img/Menu_2.png"></a></li>

    <li class="right">
    <a href="www.google.com" class="about">
    <img src="img/About_2.png"></a></li>

    <li class="right">
    <a href="www.google.com" class="contact">
    <img src="img/Contact_2.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons img{width: 190px; margin:0px; padding:0px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:55px;}
.buttons ul{list-style-type: none; margin:0px; padding:0px}

.left{float:left}
.home:hover img{display:none} 
.home:hover {background: url(../img/Home_crack.PNG);}

.right{float:right}
```

Basically i wanted to separate 4 buttons.... one in the left float and one in the right float, then on the hover, the buttons would change to a different image....With the new img{display:none} the left float rapidly flashes.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a different `img` on `:hover`, you can add it via the `:after` psuedo element with a `background-image`.

This approach works well for dynamic `img` dimensions.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/knU3v/) - different `img` will be displayed on `:hover` of `a`.

```
a:hover:after {
    content: "\A";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://...');
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting method to do this. I prefer this. +1

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the background of the `<a>` tag, which happens to be completely filled with the `<img>`. As such, the background is effectively invisible because the img is completely covering it. Try putting in a

```
.home:hover img { display: none }
```

rule as well to hide the img when you are hovered. That'll allow the background to "show".

Comment: You are also going to need a height and width with this method or the a tag will have no content in it, so it will also not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line, this will hide the orriginal image when hovering the link:

```
.home:hover img {
    display: none;
}
```

I think the other image is being showed, but the default image won't dissapear and is simply before the hover image.

Now, I do also recommend you to change the display style of the `a` element to `block` and give it a fixed size like so because the `a` element will get a size of 0 when hiding the image element:

```
.home {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Finally I recommend you to have the default image as a background in the `a` element too, just to make sure it will appear exactly the same as the hover image. Now you are using an `img` element to show the default image, a different element to show the hover image. I recommend you to prevent this, and try to use one single element. Simply add this line to achieve this:

```
.home:hover {
    background: url(../img/Home_2.png)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to everyone else here saying to add this to the css:

```
.home:hover img { display: none }
```

You will also need to add a height and width to the a tag that you are putting a background on or the tag will have no content in it and it will not show at all.

```
.home:hover {
   background: url(../img/Home_crack.PNG)
   width: [enter the width of the bg image];
   height: [enter the height of the bg image];
}
```